# updating window in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter

First of all here is some background the program.

I am trying to work my way through OOP and GUI development. I know that the code below is not great but it is my first attempt at GUI and OOP.

I have got a lot of it doing what I want (all be it probably in a very inefficient way) but I have an issue with the information I am providing to the player.

As the player progresses through the game I want them to be prompted by the program about what they should do. I have tried this with labels, buttons that have no function and text widgets (this was a complete failure).

I can get the program to create the territories as objects and then buld a GUI board using them. I can then allow the user to choose starting territories and add armies. I am just in the process of building the section that allows users to select where to attack from and where to attack. All this is working (to a fashion).

**However, My question is...
When the buttons are being updated via the functions they are still displaying the old values. Is there a way I can stop this and just have the latest message showing or am I creating new buttons each time?**

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class territory:
    def __init__ (self, country, player = 0, current_armies = 0, x=0, y=0, pos=0, neighbours=""):
        self.country = country
        self.current_armies = current_armies
        self.player = player
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.pos = pos
        self.neighbours = neighbours


    def get_armies(self):
        print(self.country + " has " + str( self.current_armies)+ " armies.")

    def add_armies (self, armies):
        self.current_armies += armies

    def roll_dice (self, dice=1):
        rolls = []
        for i in range(0, dice):
            rolls.append(random.randint(1,6))
        rolls.sort()
        rolls.reverse()
        print (self.country + " has rolled " + str(rolls))
        return rolls

    def owner(self):
        print (self.country + " is owned by " + self.player)

    def get_country(self):
        print(country)

def create_territories():
    countries = ["UK", "FRA", "SPA", "GER"]
    terr_pos = [[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0]]
    sta_arm = [1,1,1,1]
    pos = [0,1,2,3]
    neighb = [["FRA","SPA"],["UK","SPA","GER"],["FRA"],["FRA"]]
    terr = []
    for i in range(len(countries)):       
        terr.append(territory(countries[i],0, sta_arm [i] ,
                              terr_pos[i][0],terr_pos[i][1], pos[i], neighb[i]))       
    return terr

## Button Commands
def claim_t(territory, i):
    global player1_reserves, player2_reserves, cur_player, claimed, title

    if territory[i].player == 0:
        territory[i].player = cur_player
        claimed += 1

        if cur_player == 1:
            cur_player = 2
        else:
            cur_player = 1
    else:
        print("Teritory already claimed. Choose again")
    if claimed == len(territory):
        title = "Add Armies"
        message = ("player " + str(cur_player) + " add army to one of your territories.")
        army_board (territory)
    else:
        claim_board(territory)

def add_army (territories, i):
    global player1_reserves, player2_reserves, cur_player, title


    if territories[i].player == cur_player:

        if cur_player == 1:
            if player1_reserves >0:
                territories[i].current_armies += 1
                player1_reserves -= 1
                print(player1_reserves)
                cur_player = 2
            else:
                print("You have no reserves left")
                cur_player = 2
        else:
            if player2_reserves >0:
                territories[i].current_armies += 1
                player2_reserves -= 1
                print(player2_reserves)
                cur_player = 1
            else:
                print("You have no reserves left")
                cur_player = 1
        army_board (territories)
    else:
        print("Not your territory")
    if player1_reserves == 0 and player2_reserves == 0:
        cur_player = 1
        play_board(territories)
    else:
        print ("Player " + str(cur_player) +
               " add army to one of your territories.")


def run_game (territories, i):
    global attacker, defender, cur_player, attack_defend, message
    if attack_defend == "attack":
        attacker = i

        message = str(cur_player) + " has chosen to attack from " +territories[i].country + ". Choose target country."

        attack_defend = "defend"

        play_board (territories)
    else:
        if territories[i].country in territories[attacker].neighbours:
            message = "Valid Attack"
            defender = i
            attack_defend = "attack"
            play_board(territories)
        else:
            message = "You can't attack " + territories[i].country + " from " + territories[attacker].country + " Choose again"
            play_board(territories)



##    Board Builders
def claim_board(territories):
    global cur_player
    buttonUk = Button(text = territories[0].country + " p= " +
                      str(territories[0].player), width = 10,
                      command=lambda: claim_t(territories, 0),
                      fg = "red" ).grid(row=territories[0].y,column=territories[0].x)

    buttonFRA = Button(text = territories[1].country + " p= " +
                       str(territories[1].player), width = 10,
                       command=lambda: claim_t(territories, 1)).grid(row=territories[1].y,column=territories[1].x)

    buttonSpa = Button(text = territories[2].country + " p= " +
                       str(territories[2].player),
                       width = 10, command=lambda: claim_t(territories, 2)).grid(row=territories[2].y,column=territories[2].x)

    buttonGER = Button(text = territories[3].country + " p= " +
                       str(territories[3].player), width = 10,
                       command=lambda: claim_t(territories, 3)).grid(row=territories[3].y,column=territories[3].x)

    label = Label (text = "Claim your territories").grid(row=4, column = 1)

    label_1 = Label (text = "player " + str(cur_player) +
                     " add army to one of your territories.").grid(row=4, column = 1)


def army_board (territories):
    global cur_player, player1_reserves, player2_reserves
    buttonUk = Button(text = territories[0].country+
                      " a= "+str(territories[0].current_armies) +
                      " p= "+str(territories[0].player), width = 16,
                      command=lambda: add_army(territories, 0)).grid(row=territories[0].y,column=territories[0].x)

    buttonFRA = Button(text = territories[1].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[1].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[1].player), width = 16,
                       command=lambda: add_army(territories, 1)).grid(row=territories[1].y,column=territories[1].x)

    buttonSpa = Button(text = territories[2].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[2].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[2].player), width = 16,
                       command=lambda: add_army(territories, 2)).grid(row=territories[2].y,column=territories[2].x)

    buttonGER = Button(text = territories[3].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[3].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[3].player), width = 16,
                       command=lambda: add_army(territories, 3)).grid(row=territories[3].y,column=territories[3].x)

    label = Label (text = "Place your armies").grid(row=4, column = 1, columnspan = 4)

    label = Label (text = "Player " + str(cur_player) +
                   "                   place a reserve                    ").grid(row=5, column = 1, columnspan = 5)

    if cur_player == 1:
        reserves = player1_reserves
    else:
        reserves = player2_reserves

    label = Button (text = "Player " + str(cur_player) +
                    " you have " + str(reserves) +
          " reserves to place").grid(row=5, column = 1, columnspan = 4)

    print("Player " + str(cur_player) +
                    " you have " + str(reserves) +
          " reserves to place")


def play_board (territories):
    global cur_player, attacker, defender, message
    buttonUk = Button(text = territories[0].country+
                      " a= "+str(territories[0].current_armies) +
                      " p= "+str(territories[0].player),
                      width = 16, command=lambda: run_game(territories, 0)).grid(row=territories[0].y,column=territories[0].x)

    buttonFRA = Button(text = territories[1].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[1].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[1].player), width = 16, command=lambda: run_game(territories, 1)).grid(row=territories[1].y,column=territories[1].x)

    buttonSpa = Button(text = territories[2].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[2].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[2].player), width = 16, command=lambda: run_game(territories, 2)).grid(row=territories[2].y,column=territories[2].x)

    buttonGER = Button(text = territories[3].country+
                       " a= "+str(territories[3].current_armies)+
                       " p= "+str(territories[3].player), width = 16, command=lambda: run_game(territories, 3)).grid(row=territories[3].y,column=territories[3].x)

    label = Label (text = "Now it is time to wage war").grid(row=4, column = 1)

    label = Button (text = message).grid(row=5, column = 1)
    print(message)


##Game Sections

def claim_territory (territory):
    global claimed, title
    window = Tk()
    window.title ("Domination")
    if claimed != len(territory):
        claim_board(territory)
    else:
        window.destroy()
    window.mainloop()

## Global Variables
territories = create_territories()
cur_player = 1
player1_reserves = 1
player2_reserves = 1
claimed = 0
attacker = ""
defender = ""
message = "Player " + str(cur_player) + " Select a location to attack from"
attack_defend = "attack"


## Running of Game

claim_territory(territories)
```

Comment: Your button-storing variables are local to the functions which generate them. When the function ends, the buttons become inaccesible.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean here. Basically the buttons are being re-created on each call, not overwriting the old ones.

I have tried clearing the window and destroying the window but for some reason I get an error when I try to close the window.

I will re-visit this and try to build each board as a class that I hope will then allow me to edit the buttons each time.

Any thoughts or tips on where to get advice on this would be appreciated as I have come up short in my web searches.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `config` method of the `Button` class in the `Tkinkter` library to update any one of the button properties after a `Button` has been instantiated. Have a look at the documentation here:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method